# How do I configure SSRS Web Service to include missing proxy class?

Tags: soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I am new to SQL Server Reporting Services and web services in general.  I am trying to follow this tutorial for integrating java with SSRS web services: http://www.craigsprogramming.com/2011/03/how-to-integrate-java-with-microsoft_4178.html.

I have generated the proxy classes from the server's ReportExecution2005 wsdl file, using the wsimport utility. I get most classes such as the ReportExecutionService and the ReportExecutionServiceSoap.  However, I seem to be missing the ReportExecutionServiceSoapStub class which is utilized in the tutorial(and among other tutorials/examples). I have the same version of ReportExecutionService.

"import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.*;" doesn't contain ReportExecutionServiceSoapStub class

Would anyone have any idea why this is happening? This is very new to me, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the Stub class is generated by Apache Axis when the wsdl is converted to the proxy classes by Axis.  I generated them with wsimport.